# Customize Docusign notifications for same envelope, same language but different text for different people using resource files?

Tags: localization, docusignapi, resource-files, envelope

I'm still reading through the docusign email resource file.. wanted to get inputs on my scenario from experts who already know the answer:

I'm trying to achieve this:
An envelope contains multiple participants - already done
I want to send different email content (subject, body) to different participants (based on internal roles/logic).
All notifications per envelope will be in the same language
Need for localization of the email content

My understanding so far:
I see that there's capability to customize the emails to be sent in different languages
Challenge:
How do I send different email subj/body for each participants?

Comment: Are you using the API? If so, any code snippet you have already tried could be a good starting point for the community to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-blog-series-common-api-tasks-change-email-subject-and-body-for-each-recipient

Has information on how to do this using the API and SDKs.

Not sure which programming lang you'd like, here is C#:

```
// create a Signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
// add an EmailNotification object with a custom email subject and email body
Signer signer1 = new Signer {
    Email = "inbar@example.com",
    Name = "Inbar Gazit",
    RecipientId = "1",
    RoutingOrder = "1",
    EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification { 
        EmailSubject = "Custom email subject for signer 1", 
        EmailBody = "Custom email body for signer 1" }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had explored that option before and kept it as the last choice cuz it involves me (the dev) being responsible for what's sent to docusign. I wanted to segregate the duties so that the content author can have their own way of managing the content and change it as necessary. I was hoping Docusign has a way to do that off the shelf. Seems like that's not the case, so I 'll have to find a way to use xml files as part of the solution that the PM can handle independently. Thanks for responding tho!

Comment: not sure what you mean "off the shelf". This functionality is available in the DocuSign eSignature Web app, but you being a developer I assume you wanted to build it for yourself.

Comment: when i said off the shelf, i meant that docusign has the capability to send different emails to different participants by configuring the email content in docusign (resource files or such). using the api route, i need to send the text as part of the envelope. anyway i think we're on the same page. thanks I'll accept your answer

Comment: What you refer to, using resource files, is for i18n.  The resources are grouped under language.  What Inbar showed in the code above is for specifying the language-specific subject and extra email text.  If you simply want one recipient to receive an email in language_1 and the next to receive email in language_2, add them to the emailNotification element as supportedLanguage (2-letter code).

Comment: Follow up ques: I'm sending the text for the email subject and body that I want. I want to change the rest of the email (link text, standard stuff) to a different language.. how do I accomplish that via the api? I set SupportedLanguage = "fr" but the email still came in English. What am I missing?

Note: Enable custom email and language for each recipient is checked for my account

Comment: You are doing it right, but there are some caveats. For example, if you sent it to yourself to test, and you have your own settings as English - that overrides it. The user have control over the languages even if someone wants to send them in French, but they want English - it will come as English

Comment: I recommend asking a new question so that we don't confuse issues.